# Reverse Pandas groupby().agg(list)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reverse a `DataFrame.groupby().agg(list)`.

This is the initial data.

```
  PERSON  FOO  BAR
0   Maya   12    0
1   Maya    3    1
2    Jim    9    2
3    Jim    7    3
```

And that is the result `groupby().agg(list)` and some more work on it.

```
            FOO    BAR
PERSON
Jim      [9, 7]  2 | 3
Maya    [12, 3]  0 | 1
```

I **expect** a result like this

```
  PERSON  FOO  BAR
0   Maya   12  0 | 1
1   Maya    3  0 | 1
2    Jim    9  2 | 3
3    Jim    7  2 | 3
```

In words:

- I want to "unlist" the cell content in `FOO` and
- keep/duplicate the content in `BAR`.

This is a full MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'PERSON': ['Maya', 'Maya', 'Jim', 'Jim'],
        'FOO': [12, 3, 9, 7],
        'BAR': range(4)
    }
)
print(df)

# Group by Person but keep all content as list's in the cells
dfg = df.groupby('PERSON').agg(list)
# Do some work on the result
dfg.BAR = dfg.BAR.apply(lambda cell: ' | '.join([str(e) for e in cell]))

print(dfg)
```

Comment: have you tried `exploding` your df ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: Yes it is it! It is up to you to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
dfg.explode('FOO')
```